# Swift 3 - how to hide Status Bar when using Over Full Screen

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, segue

I'm developing a swift app and I can't find how to hide Status Bar when I use Over Full Screen presentation on my modal.

However, I put this line of code in my Modal View Controller :

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

And it is working if I create a segue which is not a modal, or if I create a segue which is a modal but not with Over Full Screen presentation.

I searched on internet how to fix it, and I found people who had the same problem but there had no solution.

Also, I can't change the color of my Status Bar when I'm using Over Full Screen option. I don't understand why? I think it's related.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try putting it in your appDelegate as well.

Answer (score 7):

To hide the status bar when doing an over full screen modal, you need to set this in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
    modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
}
```

Then do the standard method to hide the status bar:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: For objective-c users the viewDidLoad part will be:                                           self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = YES;

Comment: modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance works for me

Answer (score 0):

We can override `preferredStatusBarStyle` from individual view controller as you have done correctly.

Along with this, insert a new key named “*View controller-based status bar appearance*” and set the value to NO in your `info.plist`.
[image]

By disabling the “View controller-based status bar appearance”, you can set the status bar style by using the following code.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent]; //objective-c
```

Hence it should solve "I can't change the color of my Status Bar when I'm using Over Full Screen option"

Comment: This is not working for my View Controller which is a modal. I still have the black Status bar